# Erro ao exibir a soma em um SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Não estou conseguindo somar o valor total.

#### View

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Banco

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Valores que estão no banco:

*R$ 70,88

R$ 70,88

R$ 70,88*

#### Valor que aparece

> *R$ 210*

#### Valor que tem que aparecer

> R$ 212,64

#### Código

```
<?php
     $numerocontrato = trim($_GET["numerocontrato"]);
     $consulta = $DB->query("SELECT sum(valordependente) as dep FROM cadastro_clientes where numerocontrato = $numerocontrato");
     while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<h1>" . $linha['dep'] . "</h1>";
     } 
?>
```

Comment: Não tem que agrupar -> `SELECT sum(valordependente) as dep, adesao FROM cadastro_clientes where numerocontrato = $numerocontrato GROUP BY adesao`

Comment: ja fiz isso @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Coloque na pergunta uma cópia dos dados um imagem qualquer coisa!

Comment: Pronto @VirgilioNovic a imagem.

Comment: Então eu tinha que ver os dados na tabela do banco de dados essa ai não ajuda ela é um resultado de alguma lista que você fez inclusive ela somada realmente dá o valor que você precisa. Valores do banco de dados seria o ideal.

Comment: Veja ai amigo, @VirgilioNovic

Comment: se está gravando como texto ???

Comment: Sim, estou salvando como texto @VirgilioNovic, como procedo?

Comment: eu coloquei uma resposta por favor faço o teste, tem que usar 2 funções por causa disso.

Comment: @MauroSantos eu nao ia comentar novamente para deixar o Virgilio te ajudar, mas vendo que ele está ajudando da maneira errada tenho que entrar no meio, o jeito **correto** é ir no banco de dados e alterar o tipo da coluna valordependente para `DOUBLE`, pois é um tipo próprio para ligar com valores decimais. Até mais.

Comment: Obrigado @lvcs vou mudar isso, vou fazer os testes aqui e fazer o certo. Correto é Double (10,2)?

Comment: @Ivcs vou denunciar você pode editar um resposta ontem de maneira a te favorecer desculpa já que está me fazendo dessa forma também seguirei seus passos.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic qual resposta? Quando edito é com intuito de corrigir algo, e por favor, em assuntos que não se trata da pergunta comente no **chat**. PS: nada contra você, só não acho que aqui é local para gambiarra.

Comment: @Ivcs já o fiz independente do que você acha eu não faria dessa forma também, agora se tem que aprender que também tem espelho de vidro eu já sinalizei o que você fez de errado ontem numa pergunta de PHP, que é muito grave ao meu ver. Eu alertei ele que o melhor é decimal, mas, isso não compete a mim resolver ele tem que fazer no seu sistema, não tenho nada contra ninguém também, mas, receber votos sem merecer também acho inválido. Não sou eu que estou fazendo errado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O correto é você gravar esses valores em `decimal` para que não fique convertendo os dados dessa maneira abaixo:

```
<?php
   $numerocontrato = trim($_GET["numerocontrato"]);
   $sql =" SELECT sum(cast(replace(valordependente,',','.') as decimal(18,2))) as dep ";
   $sql .= " FROM cadastro_clientes where numerocontrato = $numerocontrato ";
   $consulta = $DB->query($sql);
   while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<h1>" . $linha['dep'] . "</h1>";
   }
```

Funciona, mas, se isso for feito em uma tabela aonde os resultados são muitos pode causar baixo desempenho.

Comment: -1 porque o certo é gravar o valor no banco de dados como DOUBLE ou FLOAT

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$consulta' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: @Ivcs eu sei disso eu ia falar para ele mas, isso não é culpa minha

Comment: @MauroSantos faltou um ponto e virgula.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o dever da comunidade é guiar o outro membro para um caminho correto, não deixar ele no caminho errado achando que está certo.

Comment: Apareceu 212.64 posso trocar esse (ponto) por vírgula onde? @VirgilioNovic

Comment: @Ivcs eu sei muito bem disso eu ainda estava respondendo a questão. Não vejo motivos para isso. Você compreende isso ou não?

Comment: @MauroSantos tem que formatar com `number_format` do `PHP`

Comment: Obrigado @VirgilioNovic